# How to collect retrieved data in an array from api call in NodeJS

Tags: javascript

I am used to java and I recently started a project in NodeJS and I encountered some problems with the logic behind NodeJS I think.
I have this function that needs to execute a query multiple times (changing the parameters at every iteration) and store the result in an array.

I created an array variable `let FINAL = []` and i am trying to push in data when the data is retrieved per iteration.

```
const fluxAccesParPeriode = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const db = res.locals.db;
        const {date_debut, date_fin} = req.body;

        if (!date_debut || !date_fin) {
            res.status(400).json({error: 'One or more informations are missing.'});
            return;
        }

        // SQL
        const queryText = "SELECT COUNT(id_pointage) AS nbreAcces FROM pointage_adherents PA, adherents A WHERE PA.id_adherent=A.id_adherent AND date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND heure_entree BETWEEN ? AND ?";

        let FINAL = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 24; i += 3) {
            let heure_debut = i + ":00:00";
            let heure_fin = (i + 3) + ":00:00";

            await db.execute(queryText,
                [date_debut, date_fin, heure_debut, heure_fin],
                (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
                        res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal Server Error'});
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log(heure_debut + "  /   " + heure_fin + "  /  " + results[0]["nbreAcces"]);

                    FINAL.push({heure_debut: heure_debut, heure_fin: heure_fin, result: results[0]["nbreAcces"]});
                });
        }

        console.log("RESULT : " + FINAL);

        if (FINAL.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).json(FINAL);
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({error: 'Error while executing your query: fluxAccesParPeriode'});
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.stack);
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Erreur lors de l\'exécution de la requête'});
    }
}
```

What i noticed is that the last `console.log`  is printed first before the `console.log` inside the loop. I tried to add `await` but still the same issue.

Here is an image of what I am getting in the terminal:

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Your call to  `await db.execute(query,variable,callback),` looks like it is using the callback paradigm instead of promises,  so the `await` doesn't do anything since the call to db.execute isn't returning a promise. You can probably [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `await db.execute(query,variable,callback)` looks like it is using the callback paradigm instead of promises, so the await doesn't do anything since the call to `db.execute` isn't returning a promise.

I'm not sure if promisify [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) will work, since it probably needs the binding to `db`, but it is easy to promisify the call on the fly.

Since you have the for-loop inside a try/catch block I remove the exit from inside the lopp to throwing an exception with `reject`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 24; i += 3) {
  let heure_debut = i + ':00:00';
  let heure_fin = i + 3 + ':00:00';
  const results = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.execute(queryText, [date_debut, date_fin, heure_debut, heure_fin], (err, results) =>
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(results)
    );
  });

  console.log(heure_debut + '  /   ' + heure_fin + '  /  ' + results[0]['nbreAcces']);

  FINAL.push({ heure_debut: heure_debut, heure_fin: heure_fin, result: results[0]['nbreAcces'] });
}
```

A suggestion: You can probably rewrite the SQL query to let the database do the grouping. That will improve performance and only requires one call to the database.

Comment: This piece of code seems to work, i had to modify a bit in the `console.log`, I changed it to `console.log(heure_debut + '  /   ' + heure_fin + '  /  ' + util.inspect(results[0]));` so it can print something, but apparently the `result` variable is showing [Circular] and i dont know what is that tbh. Also the data is getting pushed into `FINAL` so that's a good start

Comment: To be honest, I just copied your code. If you instead of concatenating a string with `+` use a comma `,` console.log will do what you want.

Comment: About the `[Circular]`: In my example I misspelled `results` as `result` in some places. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that and fixed it, the thing is that `results` is supposed to return a number, but in my case its returning `[Circular]`

Comment: What do you get if you just `console.log(results)`?

Comment: `[]` its totally empty i dont know why, if I execute the query in the database it returns a number, but nothing here

Comment: What database and library are you using? Do you also get an empty array if you `console.log(results)` inside the callback, before the return statement?

Comment: I am using MySQL for database, and mysql2 for the library. My head is spinning with this problem so i missed some stuff, i cleared the code and successfully printed `results`, your code works, it indeed return `[{"nbreAcces":645}]`. Now i have a new problem with pushing the data into `FINAL`, the `result` data does not get pushed, `heure_debut` and `heure_fin` are fine but `result` nothing

Comment: I finally did it, that's how i made the push  `FINAL.push({heure_debut: heure_debut, heure_fin: heure_fin, result: results[0]["nbreAcces"]});` works like a charm

Comment: I don't see the difference. Was it because my earlier misspelling? By the way, you don't need to access it with a string like `results[0]["nbreAcces"]` but can use `results[0].nbreAcces` as long as it doesn't start with a number and is a legal identifier.

Comment: Yea maybe, ive been on the computer for several hours now so i am low on concentration, i was using `resolve(FINAL)` for some reason instead of `resolve(results)`. Okay thank you ill change the access thing.

Comment: Ah, in my first version I had misspelled it as `result` instead of `results`, you copied it and since it didn't work you replaced it with `FINAL`. Since I fixed it in my code, I assumed you fixed it in yours, and that's why it didn't make sense with `[circular]`. I know how frustrating it is when you try to solve a problem for hours. A piece of advice: take a break. Think of something else for a while. Then do some Rubber duck debugging (look it up). It usually solves the problem.

Comment: Yea this is definetly what happened, thank you for your advice tho i took some time and im ready to carry on now. Ill also look for the Rubber duck debugging hopefully it will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is how [node js event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick) works. For loop will run and put all the db query in a queue and surpass the loop and print the last "RESULT" log.

Then whatever query is resolved and get the response from DB, that particular query will print the log. thats why you have random sequence.

Best Solution for this will be to use [promise all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method something like:

```js
const fluxAccesParPeriode = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const db = res.locals.db;
        const { date_debut, date_fin } = req.body;

        if (!date_debut || !date_fin) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: 'One or more informations are missing.' });
            return;
        }

        // SQL
        const queryText = "SELECT COUNT(id_pointage) AS nbreAcces FROM pointage_adherents PA, adherents A WHERE PA.id_adherent=A.id_adherent AND date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND heure_entree BETWEEN ? AND ?";
        let FINAL = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 24; i += 3) {
            let heure_debut = i + ":00:00";
            let heure_fin = (i + 3) + ":00:00";
            FINAL.push(db.execute(queryText, [date_debut, date_fin, heure_debut, heure_fin]));
        }

        const results = await Promise.all(FINAL);

        results.forEach(element => {
            console.log(heure_debut + "  /   " + heure_fin + "  /  " + results[0]["nbreAcces"]);
        });
        console.log("RESULT : " + results);

         res.status(200).json(results);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.stack);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Erreur lors de l\'exécution de la requête' });
    }
}
```